# "Слушатель" java script генерирует события при вводе в форму с клавиатуры, но при копировании из буфера обмена не срабатывает!

Tags: javascript

Хочу редактировать ввод пользователя прямо во время заполнения формы (номера телефона). 1-я функция сходу меняет любую 8 на +7, а 2-я фиксирует размер строки и меняет +7 на +78, если вводили питерский номер в неполном формате.. При вводе с клавиатуры все работает, а вот когда копируешь из буфера - "восемь" не добавляется.. Почему.. голову сломал.. Извините за глупый вопрос, совсем не разбираюсь в Java Script..

**Как программа должна работать:** Пользователь вводит номер телефона или копирует из буфера обмена. Вначале первая буква меняет 8 на +7, затем вторая функция узнает о количестве символов и возвращает 8-ку, если вводился питерский номер в неполном формате..

**Разъяснение по формату номеров, который нужно получить:**Необходимо, чтобы при введении с клавиатуры или копировании из буфера обмена любой вид приводился к +7 XXX XX XX, без пробелов, тире и скобок.. Первая функция, которая заменяет восьмерку сразу же нужна, чтобы изменения вносили одновременно с действиями пользователя.. Например, пользователь копирует номер 89065555555, 8 меняется на +7, после этого нужно проверить по количеству цифр не убрана ли 8 зря..
Результаты проверки с помощью console.log:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('#telefon');

  if (input) {
    input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
      const currentElement = event.currentTarget;
      if (currentElement.value.length && currentElement.value[0] === '8') {
        currentElement.value = `+7${currentElement.value.substring(1)}`;
      }
    })
  }
})

function addFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementById("telefon").value;
  let c = x.length;
  if (c === 11) {
    k = x.replace("+7", "+78");
    document.getElementById("telefon").value = "".concat(k);
  }

  if (numbers[0] == 8) numbers = numbers.substring(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="telefon">Phone</label>
  <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefon" value="" oninput="addFunction()">
</div>
```

Comment: покажи пример номера с которым функция не работает

Comment: А где идет вызов функции `addFunction`?

Comment: Andrey Freiz, вот пример номера: 8127848909. Не набиваю, а копирую - замена на "+78" не происходит, только +7 появляется - остальное в неизменном виде..

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, функция вызывается в <input>, вот так: "oninput="addFunction()", не в вызове дела, простите, я более поздний кусочек кода к вопросу приложил..

Comment: В остальном все точно корректно..

Comment: @Valentin, в сниппете не воспроизводтся работает именно тот обработчик, который меняет первую 8 на +7. Если ты ожидал какое-то другое поведение, добавь в вопрос какое именно поведение ожидал, и отредактируй сниппет так, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @Grundy постарался сделать свой текст понятнее на основе ваших замечаний.. Написал в вопросе, как программа должна работать, код привел в полное соответствие с тем, который не сработал и по поводу которого задается вопрос..

Comment: Добавь еще пример, какой номер надо вставить и какой результат ожидается. Плюс попробуй добавить console.log в функции и посмотри - когда твои обработчики срабатывают и в какой последовательности.

Comment: @Grundy, извините за задержку с ответом: судя по console.log, первой отрабатывает addEventListener, а затем addFunction().. Примеры номеров добавил в вопрос..

Comment: _судя по console.log, первой отрабатывает addEventListener, а затем addFunction()_ - в каком браузере ты пробовал? Ты уверен, что в нужное место лог поставил?

Comment: `if (numbers[0] == 8) numbers = numbers.substring(1);` - вот эта строчка странная - `nubmers` нигде не определено - непонятно что она делает

Comment: При вводе `89065555555` - какой результат должен получиться?

Comment: @Gurundy, простите, ради бога, за задержки с ответами. По console.log: пробовал в Furefox и Chrome..

Comment: @Gurundy, console.log точно все правильно вставил, приложил к вопросу картинку: как это было сделано..

Comment: @Gurundy, из 89065555555 нужно получить +79065555555, другое дело, что если ввели номер без восьмерки, но с первой восьмерке в коде города, допустим, 8165555555, нужно заменять ве это дело на правильный формат..

Answer (score 0):

Valentin, уверен, что всё это можно было бы уточнить в Вашем прошлом вопросе [Как "на лету" перезаписать вводимый в input формы телефон? Требуется "подхватить" ввод, изменить и сразу вставить обратно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163306/)

Вам необходимо обрабатывать событие input всё же в одной функции, а не дробить обработку события на 2 функции.
Пожалуй, в Вашем случае подойдет небольшой фикс:

```
input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const currentElement = event.currentTarget;
    if (currentElement.value.length && currentElement.value[0] === '8') {
        const cutValue = currentElement.value.length === 10 ? 0 : 1
        currentElement.value = `+7${currentElement.value.substring(cutValue)}`;
    }
})
```

И функция "addFunction" просто станет не нужна.

Хочу так же отметить, что можно использовать готовые решения для создания маски ввода. Есть и для jquery:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Так и нативные варианты:
https://imask.js.org/

Comment: Не отрабатывает, к сожалению.. Почитал про регулярные выражения, попробовал в разных вариациях.. В консоли ошибок не выдает, но и восемь где нужно не подставляет и не убирает..

Comment: Насколько я понял, все дело в первом условии.. оно сразу меняет +7, и после этого назад не действует.. Не до конца понимаю, как listener работает..

Comment: Метод addEventListener (дословно с англ. "Добавить слушателя на событие"), собственно, добавляет слушателя (функцию) на указанное событие у DOM-элемента. Т.е. Своими словами можно сказать так:
DOM-элемент инпут, слушай событие "input" и когда оно произойдет - выполни, пожалуйста, такую-то функцию. у метода addEventListener 2 аргумента. Первым аргументом мы передаем название события. А вторым - функцию, которую необходимо выполнить.

Comment: В любом случае, вы мне очень помогли..

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Паллиатив, но работает.. Функция excludeEight() таки убирает 8, и срабатывает после listener, другое дело, что приходится в input onchange="" добавлять.. программа в этом случае срабатывает даже при копировании из буфера обмена, но не сразу, а когда окно ввода "теряет фокус"

```
<script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const input = document.querySelector('#addNumber');
    
      if (input) {
        input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
          const currentElement = event.currentTarget;
          if (currentElement.value.length && currentElement.value[0] === '8') {
            currentElement.value = `+7${currentElement.value.substring(1)}`;
            console.log("hj");
          }
            
          else if (currentElement.value.length === 10 && currentElement.value[0] !== '8' && currentElement.value[0] !== '+') {
              currentElement.value = `+7${currentElement.value.substring(0)}`;
          }
            
            if (currentElement.value.length === 11 && currentElement.value[0] == '+' && currentElement.value[2] !== '8') {
              currentElement.value = `+78${currentElement.value.substring(2)}`;
            }
            
        })
      }
    })
    
    function excludeEight() {
      let x = document.getElementById("addNumber").value;
      let c = x.length;
      if (c > 12) {
        let k = x.replace("+78", "+7");
        document.getElementById("addNumber").value = "".concat(k);
        console.log("lk");
      }
      
    }
    
    </script>
```